# The application was unable to start correctly 0xc000007b selenium-manager.exe

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

i have a c# application that use selenium

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using System;
using System.Threading;
```

running the program on most of the computers (windows 10 or 11) is working fine
i have one windows 11 computer that get selenium-manager error
[image]

what can cause that?
try:

1. change the  selenium version
2. install java
   non is working :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170#visual-studio-2015-2017-2019-and-2022

solved the issue (it was  selenium  issue not c#)